# ios assign self to property in another class

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, nsobject

I'm trying to assign self to a property in antoher class (nsobject class) using self as pointer to the view controller but the property is always nil. Any of you knows why or how can I fixed?

viewcontroller.m

```
-(void)startToDoSomething:(NSString*)testToRun
{
    SecondClass *secondClass = [[SecondClass alloc] init];
    secondClass.viewController = self;
    [secondClass doSomething];
}
```

SecondClass.h:

NSObject classe:

.h file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@class ViewController;

@interface SecondClass : NSObject
{
    ViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) ViewController *viewController;
```

Comment: How is the `viewController` declared/implemented in `SecondClass`?

Comment: secondClass is declare (#import secondClass) and the property is declare in the secondClass.h

Comment: I had add the secondclass.h content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you add an init method:

```
-(id)initWithViewController:(ViewController *)aViewController
{
     self = [super init];

     if(self)
     {
          self.viewController = aViewController;
     }

     return self;
}
```

Then you can just call it like this

```
SecondClass *secondClass = [[SecondClass alloc] initWithViewController:self];
```

You can also change the property to `(nonatomic, assign)` and change the synthesize to `@synthesize viewController =  _viewController`

Inside the SecondClass you use _viewController.

Hope it helps.